# Latex in R Markdown & Greek Letters

Tags: latex, r-markdown

This is the equation I would like to type into R Markdown:

Pr⁡(treat ends|t,s)=Φ(β_0+β_1 t+β_2 t^2+μ_s )

This is my latex code at the moment:

$P(treat end|t, s) = $\Phi(\beta *{0}+\beta*{1}t+\beta_{2}t^{2}+\mu_{s})

I get an error when I try to knit to pdf. There seems to be a problem with the $\Phi, but I can't seem to figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution:

$$P(treat end|t, s) = \Phi(\beta *{0}+\beta*{1}t+\beta_{2}t^{2}+\mu_{s})$$